# How do we know which graph api version we are using from the SDK

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Once in a while, we get this email from Facebook about a graph API is about to be deprecated.

We are using both the iOS SDK and Android SDK in our apps.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

I know the SDK use the graph API internally, but I find it tricky to tell which version of the graph API we are using from the SDK.

Is there a way to tell which graph API version we are using given the SDK version number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this can help you, because in this changelog it is written that in which SDK version which GRAPH API version was used.

- versions >= 5: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
- versions <5: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x

Answer (score 21):

For iOS, if you are not calling the method named `+ (void)setGraphAPIVersion:(NSString *)version` anywhere in the project, you should be using the version defined with `FBSDK_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION`. You can find it in `FBSDKCoreKit.h` file as below:

[image]

Or:

You can also try to log `[FBSDKSettings graphAPIVersion];`

Comment: Hi, For iOS I do not have FBSDKCoreKit.h but rather FBSDKGraphRequest.h file. And this file have FBSDK_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION mentioned inside comment as,                                                                                                
#@param version the optional Graph API version (e.g., @"v2.0"). nil defaults to FBSDK_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION.